# How can I ensure the model to not change order of training dataset during training?

Tags: tensorflow, dataset

I have three different orders of my dataset for an NLP project, and I would like to apply curriculum learning in TensorFlow, but I don't know which parameter I should use to keep the order I provided. For instance, in the first dataset, I have complex to simple order; in the second dataset, I have simple to complex order, etc. To understand if the curriculum matters, I have to keep the training dataset as I ordered.

I tried to train my model with different orders of my dataset but I didn't get any different result. I think during training the model shuffles my dataset in the same way so I didn't get different results.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using [tf.data.Dataset](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/data/Dataset) as your training data, it will not be shuffled during training. If you are using other format (e.g. ordinary numpy array), you can provide parameter `shuffle=False` in the `model.fit` method.

From documentation for [tf.keras.Model.fit](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/Model#fit):

> shuffle: Boolean (whether to shuffle the training data before each epoch) or str (for 'batch'). This argument is ignored when x is a generator or an object of tf.data.Dataset. 'batch' is a special option for dealing with the limitations of HDF5 data; it shuffles in batch-sized chunks. Has no effect when steps_per_epoch is not None.

Default value for `shuffle` is `True`, so you might have to provide it as `False` if your data is not in the form of generator or `tf.data.Dataset`.

Comment: Thank you so much for your helpful answer! Your contribution has made a significant difference in my project..